# Remove xml elements and parent nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio

for some reason when I put "SDB0000013E" or any other value than "SDB0000012E" in my textbox the xml code is not removed. if i want to remove the first bit of my xml(SDB0000012E) it works perfectly. I dont understand whay this is happening. any help on this would be great. Thanks

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
    Dim xdoc As XmlDocument
    Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList

    xdoc = New XmlDocument
    Dim xmlData As String = path & FileXml
    xdoc.Load(xmlData)
    nodelist = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("DataTable")

    Dim intNdeCnt As Integer = 0
    Dim lstNodeErrs As New List(Of String)

    For Each node1 As XmlElement In nodelist

        intNdeCnt += 1
        lstNodeErrs.Add("------ Checking node: " & intNdeCnt)
        REFNO = node1("REFNO ").InnerText.Trim
        MEMO_NO = node1("MEMO_NO").InnerText.Trim
        Code = node1("Code").InnerText.Trim

       If CheckBox2.Checked Then
                Dim DocPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(path, "data.xml")
                Dim doc As XElement
                doc = XElement.Load(DocPath) 'to load from file

                'use TextBox1 to match ASI_REF
                Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
                ie = From el In doc...<ASI_REF>
                     Where el.Value = TextBox1.Text
                     Select el

                For idx As Integer = ie.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    Dim xe As XElement = ie(idx)

                    xe.Parent.Remove() 'this removes the DataTable node
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted: " & REFNO.ToString)
                Next
                doc.Save(DocPath)
        End If

        ' -- Test data

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(REFNO) Then
            lstNodeErrs.Add("REFNO Is blank.")
        END If


        If lstNodeErrs.Count > 1 Then

                For Each strNodErr As String In lstNodeErrs
                    lstErrs.Add(strNodErr)
                Next
                lstErrs.Add("")

                If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                    lstErrs.Add(vbCrLf & node1("REFNO").ParentNode.OuterXml)

                End If

            End If

            lstNodeErrs.Clear()

        Next
```

> xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" standalone="yes"?>
<data_xml>
    <DataTable>
        <REFNO>SDB0000012E</REFNO>
        <MEMO_NO>5191647556</MEMO_NO>
        <Code>0145191647556</Code>
    </DataTable>
    <DataTable>
        <REFNO>SDB0000013E</REFNO>
        <MEMO_NO>5191647504</MEMO_NO>
        <Code>0145191647504</Code>
    </DataTable>
    <DataTable>
        <REFNO>SDB0000014E</REFNO>
        <MEMO_NO>5191647504</MEMO_NO>
        <Code>0145191647504</Code>
    </DataTable>
</data_xml>
```

> when I put a breakpoint in even though i was typing "SDB0000013E" into the textbox it was still reading SDB0000012E on line:

```
If elem.InnerText = TextBox1.Text Then
```

> over the InnerText bit it reads SDB0000012E  but the over the text it is reading SDB0000013E.

Comment: Which element are you trying to remove(REFNO, DataTable)?

Comment: I am trying to remove the datatable that has refno "whatever I put into my text box" eg. SDB0000012E

Answer (score 0):

This works with literals

```
    Dim DocPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Path, "data.xml")
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        Dim doc As XElement
        'doc = XElement.Load(DocPath) 'to load from file
        'if not Testing i.e. XElement.Load(DocPath)
        'remove the following doc = through 'end for Testing
        'for Testing
        doc = <data_xml>
                  <DataTable>
                      <REFNO>SDB0000012E</REFNO>
                      <MEMO_NO>5191647556</MEMO_NO>
                      <Code>0145191647556</Code>
                  </DataTable>
                  <DataTable>
                      <REFNO>SDB0000013E</REFNO>
                      <MEMO_NO>5191647504</MEMO_NO>
                      <Code>0145191647504</Code>
                  </DataTable>
                  <DataTable>
                      <REFNO>SDB0000012E</REFNO>
                      <MEMO_NO>5191647556</MEMO_NO>
                      <Code>0145191647556</Code>
                  </DataTable>
              </data_xml>
        'end for Testing

        'use TextBox1 to match REFNO
        Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
        ie = From el In doc...<REFNO>
             Where el.Value = TextBox1.Text
             Select el

        ''??? is there only one possible match?
        'If ie.Count > 0 Then
        '    'not sure what you want here
        '    'ie(0).Remove() 'this removes the REFNO node
        '    'ie(0).Parent.Remove() 'this removes the DataTable node

        '    ' doc.Save(DocPath)
        'End If

        'if multiple REFNO node matches TextBox1.Text
        For idx As Integer = ie.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim xe As XElement = ie(idx)
            'not sure what you want here
            'xe.Remove() 'this removes the REFNO node
            xe.Parent.Remove() 'this removes the DataTable node
        Next
        ' doc.Save(DocPath) ' save once if doing multiple
    End If
```

EDIT: this works using a file

```
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        Dim DocPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Path, "data.xml")
        Dim doc As XElement
        doc = XElement.Load(DocPath) 'to load from file

        'use TextBox1 to match REFNO
        Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
        ie = From el In doc...<REFNO>
             Where el.Value = TextBox1.Text
             Select el

        For idx As Integer = ie.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim xe As XElement = ie(idx)
            'not sure what you want here
            'xe.Remove() 'this removes the REFNO node
            xe.Parent.Remove() 'this removes the DataTable node
        Next
        doc.Save(DocPath) ' save once if doing multiple
    End If
```

Comment: @789 - How so? I have edited my post to show the code in a production environment.  Try it.

Comment: thank you for your help but unfortunatly as with my other code it only allows me to delete the first set of xml elements even if I have SDB0000012E in my text box

Comment: whatever set of xml I have at the top of the file works but if I try to remove xml elements that dont have a REFNO thats the first one in my xml it wont work. do  you have any idea as to why this is happening

Comment: @789 - in the test code(not the edit) I put SDB0000012E in the textbox and it deleted both(I added one).  I'm guessing you are not explaining this in a manner that makes the problem clear.

Comment: sorry yes im probably not explaining it great. I am loading my xml from a file. when I put SDB0000012E(the first group of elements in the xml fil) in the textbox it deletes both child nodes and parent nodes. It does everything as it should. but when i put in SDB0000013E( or infact any other REFNO id) the program does not delete anything. and I am not sure as to why this is happening. I get the same problem when I use your sample code as I do with mine.let me know if this makes sense. thanks for your help so far @dbasnett

Comment: whatever <dataTable> I put first the removal works for that ie. if I put DataTable with REFNO SDB0000014E and put SDB0000014E in my textbox it worksfor that REFNO but no others

Comment: @789 - How is the code triggered?  Is it in a button?  Are you changing the path?  I have been running the test code in a Button click and it works.

Comment: I am reading in a txt file and converting it to xml. yes the path is the same as always throughout my code. I am also using a button click. I just dont understand how it can work for the firat set of xml and not the rest. I will keep investigationg into it.

Comment: using your code when I debug it on the line: ie = From el In doc...<REFNO> Where el.Value = TextBox1.Text Select el. doc...<ref> read SDB0000012E and Where el.Value = TextBox1.Text Select reads SDB0000013E. I was trying to remove SDB0000013E but still nothing

Comment: @789 - so I used a button, copied the XML to a file, and it worked as expected.  Go to your original post and edit it with the entire button code you have.

Comment: @789 - take my edit code above and put it into a new button as a test.  Does it work?  You put the code I provided inside of a For-Next loop.

Comment: just tried it there in its own button and still the same prioblem. ill add more code to show the reason for the for loop

Comment: @789 - you put the edit code above in a button and it didn't work?  That was all you put in the button?  If so I can't help.  It works fine on my machine.

Comment: I dont think its the code that doesnt work I  think its formatting or something like that cause why does it work for the first REFNO of xml but not any other.? this is what I have been trying to solve. I added the extra code to show you my structure and make sure thats not whats causing it

Comment: @789 - The point of putting it in a button was to simplify the steps.  If you put the code in a button and use BREAKPOINTS the answer should be clear.  When you figure that out then you can figure out why the code can't be in the loop.

Comment: but I alreay did that? when I ran it in its own button I got the same problem, I put in breakpoints and thats how I figured out it only works for the first REFNO. the code I wrote myself has the exact same result as your edited one. my question was "when I put "SDB0000013E" or any other value than "SDB0000012E" in my textbox the xml code is not removed. if i want to remove the first bit of my xml(SDB0000012E) it works perfectly. I dont understand whay this is happening. any help on this would be great". and I still have that same question.

Comment: @789 Check out my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tested.  It has a few more comments including before and after of the file.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        Dim DocPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(FolderNM, "data.xml")
        Dim DOC As XElement
        DOC = XElement.Load(DocPath) 'to load from file
        'DOC contents before
        ''   <data_xml>
        ''     <DataTable>
        ''       <REFNO>SDB0000012E</REFNO>
        ''       <MEMO_NO>5191647556</MEMO_NO>
        ''       <Code>0145191647556</Code>
        ''     </DataTable>
        ''     <DataTable>
        ''       <REFNO>SDB0000013E</REFNO>
        ''       <MEMO_NO>5191647504</MEMO_NO>
        ''       <Code>0145191647504</Code>
        ''     </DataTable>
        ''     <DataTable>
        ''       <REFNO>SDB0000012E</REFNO>
        ''       <MEMO_NO>5191647556</MEMO_NO>
        ''       <Code>0145191647556</Code>
        ''     </DataTable>
        ''   </data_xml>

        'use TextBox1 to match REFNO
        ' Test TextBox1 = SDB0000012E
        Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
        ie = From el In DOC...<REFNO>
             Where el.Value = TextBox1.Text
             Select el

        For idx As Integer = ie.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim xe As XElement = ie(idx)
            xe.Parent.Remove() 'this removes the DataTable node
        Next

        'DOC contents after
        ''  <data_xml>
        ''    <DataTable>
        ''      <REFNO>SDB0000013E</REFNO>
        ''      <MEMO_NO>5191647504</MEMO_NO>
        ''      <Code>0145191647504</Code>
        ''    </DataTable>
        ''  </data_xml>
        DOC.Save(DocPath) ' save once if doing multiple
    End If
End Sub
```

The only way this does not work is if the XML is different.  What do you get when you run this?

Comment: I have lots of xml thats why I  am loading it rather than writting it all out. I just put a sample of it up in my question but it all follows the same structure.  I will test this later thanks so much for going to the hassel of writing another sample answer.

Comment: I still recieve the same problem. there is clearly nothing wrong with your code so it must be something else.